# can not handle swing button event when run form applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

This is my applet

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet{
 public void init(){

 }

 public void start(){
  Swsmall b = new Swsmall();


 }
}
```

This is my Swsmall file

```
public Swsmall() {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Stand alone");
  JButton jl = new JButton("Exits properly");

  frame.getContentPane().add(jl);
  frame.setSize(180,80);
  frame.setVisible(true);



        jl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.exit(0);}});
            }
```

this my jsp file

```
<body>
    <applet code="TestApplet.class" width="400" height="400"></applet>
  </body>
```

I am able to run applet successfully but I can't get any responce on button click event

When I run same application on java console it works perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame.dispose();
```

Code for creating the JFrame should be placed in the init() method. You should also be using the invokeAndWait() method.

Read the section from the Swing tuorial on [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for more information and a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Calling System.exit(0) from Java applet will not destroy an applet. Try calling something else from action listener (i.e. System.out.println("something"); would print in Java applet console), and you'll see that it's called correctly, but in this case it probably doesn't work as you expected it to work.

Comment: It will not work event i do something else in button action event

Comment: It works for me, check your Java console (it should throw an exception after calling System.exit -> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)).

Comment: Yes you are right but its gives me same error for all case not only for Sytem.exit(0). Is it give me error even if i can't click it in case when i have System.exit(0) on one button out of three?